# Disable auto-complete of name in Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Outlook 2013 has introduced an editor feature that suggests to insert my full name whenever I start typing my first name.

[image]

This is really annoying because I generally want to use only my first name in greetings but not my full name (i.e. "Thanks, Daniel", instead of "Thanks, Daniel Lang").

How can I disable auto-complete / auto-insert of my Name?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have found an answer to this now, but in case anyone else has the same problem, here is how I fixed it:

To remove this annoying feature, create a new e-mail message and from the insert menu, select "Quick parts" and then "Auto text". Right click one of the quick parts and select "Organize and delete", this will open something called the "Building blocks organizer". Remove the quickparts containing your name and... Voila - the annoying autocomplete is gone.

(Perhaps there is an easyer way to access the "Building blocks organizer", but the way I described works)

(Note: also looks like you need to have "compose in HTML" (or possible rich text) enabled)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works also very well in Outlook 2010.

Comment: and in outlook 2016, as well